# Numbers always rounding up vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hello Everyone Good Afternoon, I have a problem with my codes and Its giving me a hard time to fix this, I hope someone Helps me with this.

I have 3 `Textboxes` they are:

```
GrandTotal.Text
VatAmount.Text
TotalAmount.Text
```

and 1 `NumericUpDown1` that works as Percent Identifier.

Here is the Scenario of my Program, I will press a Button then a certain column in my Datagridview will compute and transfer the SUM in the `GrandTotal.Text` (**Note the Number will Display with Commas and Decimal Points (Acts as a Cent)**) and after that I will press `NumericUpdown1.Value`, Lets say I press it 1 time and value of `NumericUpdown1.Value` is **1** equivalent to **1 percent** and after the value changes the `VatAmount.Text` will Display how much is the **1 percent** of the `GrandTotal.Text` and `TotalAmount.Text`will Display the Sum of `GrandTotal.Text` and `VatAmount.Text`.

My Goal Here is to Display the Numbers with Commas and 2 Decimal Points(**Acting as a Cents**)

Here is my Code inside the Textboxes so that Numbers will Display in Commas and Decimal Points.

Inside `GrandTotal.Text`

```
 Private Sub grandtotal_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grandtotal.TextChanged
        Try
            grandtotal.Text = FormatNumber(grandtotal.Text, 2, True, True, True)
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Inside `VatAmount.Text`

```
 Private Sub VatAmount_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles VatAmount.TextChanged
        Try
            VatAmount.Text = FormatNumber(VatAmount.Text, 2, True, True, True)
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
```

and Inside `TotalAmount.Text`

```
 Private Sub totalamount_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles totalamount.TextChanged
        Dim dblValue As Decimal = totalamount.Text
        totalamount.Text = dblValue.ToString("0,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
End Sub
```

And Here is the Code that will do the Computation and it is Inside `NumericUpDown1.Value`

```
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged

        Dim input As Double = Decimal.Parse(grandtotal.Text)
        Dim inputStringWithCommas As Decimal = input.ToString("0,0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        grandtotal.Text = inputStringWithCommas
        Dim vat As Double = Double.Parse(grandtotal.Text) * NumericUpDown1.Value * 0.01
        VatAmount.Text = vat.ToString()
        totalamount.Text = Decimal.Parse(grandtotal.Text) + vat.ToString("0,0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    End Sub
```

I Hope you Understand my Explanation, I just wanted it to be in Detail.

Here is my Question but before that Let me give you some Example Output.

In My Calculator

1st Example

150,001.50 * 1 Percent(0.01) = 1,500.015

1,500.015 + 150,001.50 = 151,501.51

But in my Program the output is like this. :(

[image]

Now you see It, You can see the Difference in the Output, My Question here is How can I make my output same as the example in My Calculator? Proper Commas and Decimal Places (**2 Decimal Places in `TotalAmount.Text` and NO Rounding Off just Cut 2 Decimal Places**)

Thank you for Reading this Post and Really Thank you for future Help.
Im Using VB.Net

Comment: If you use `150,001.50 * 0.01` the answer seems to be rounded to the same amount of decimals that you use. Try changing all `Double`s to `Decimal`. Decimal has a higher precision in general and is supposed to be used when calculating currency (it also minimizes the chance of automatic rounding). If that doesn't work, still use Decimal but try to divide instead: `New Decimal(150,001.50) / New Decimal(1 / 0.01)`.

Comment: `Decimal` being preferred to `Double` was explained to you [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343901/proper-computation-of-numbers#comment62205678_37343901) in a double upvoted comment.  See also [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code to cut decimals:

```
decimal d = 123.129M;

int multiplier = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, 2));
decimal newD = Math.Truncate(d * multiplier) / multiplier;
```

**EDIT**

You can create a function is a Module file in VB, with common functions, something like:

```
    Public Function TrimDecimals(value As Double, maxDecimals As Integer) As Double
        Dim multiplier As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, maxDecimals))
        Return Math.Truncate(value * multiplier) / multiplier
    End Function

    Public Function TrimDecimals(value As Decimal, maxDecimals As Integer) As Double
        Dim multiplier As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, maxDecimals))
        Return Math.Truncate(value * multiplier) / multiplier
    End Function
```

or even better, you can create extensions on double and decimal for more elegant approach:

```
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function TrimDecimals(value As Double, maxDecimals As Integer) As Double
        Dim multiplier As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, maxDecimals))
        Return Math.Truncate(value * multiplier) / multiplier
    End Function

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function TrimDecimals(value As Decimal, maxDecimals As Integer) As Double
        Dim multiplier As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, maxDecimals))
        Return Math.Truncate(value * multiplier) / multiplier
    End Function
```

There are some issues but please try:

```
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
        Dim grandtotalValue As Decimal = TrimDecimals(Decimal.Parse(grandtotal.Text), 2)
        grandtotal.Text = grandtotalValue.ToString("#,##0.00")

        Dim vatValue As Double = TrimDecimals(grandtotalValue * NumericUpDown1.Value * 0.01, 2)
        VatAmount.Text = vatValue.ToString("#,##0.00")

        totalamount.Text = (grandtotalValue + vatValue).ToString("#,##0.00")
    End Sub
```

Comment: How can I put that Sir in my Code? :(

Comment: I will try this code by tomorrow and update you right ahead. TYSM :)

Comment: What more I can say, Such a Big Help. :) TYSM

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I posted this Question last Saturday and I only tried it Today TYSM!